# My webpage cannot find the link from my firebase real time database snippet

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to connect my webpage to firebase but it is not working out.
It tells me it can't find the firebase links.
What can I do?

**Code for my firebase snippet**

```
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/8.1.1/firebase-database.js"></script>


<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="/__/firebase/8.1.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

**JS code**

```
    database = firebase.database();
    database.ref("/Controls/" + userId.value).set({
                    "name":controlName, 
                })


picture of the error message
```

[image]

Comment: kindly verify the path to your scripts are correct. They should be relative to your folder. You look at the error message and you know the path is wrong.

Comment: The script includes you're using are for use with Firebase Hosting only.  They will not work with pages deployed elsewhere.

Comment: ok noted. Issue has been resolved by copying the firebase project CDN snippet and put it at the end of HTML <body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as mentioned before, the link files were not properly addressed.

Solution:
At the firebase app settings, I copied the CDN snippet of the app and its database and then pasted them at the bottom of my  tag.

It works just fine now.